# Need options to limit the memory in hive on map joins

Tags: hive

how to limit the memory used in a map join, how can I control it .

lets say I make join of two huge tables( each 10 million records with 10 columns). can I control the memory that I can allot for that job ?

thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the maximum size of a table to be used in a map join (as the small table) is 1,000,000,000 bytes (about 1 GB)

If you want to increase this,

```
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=2000000000;
```